# A famous book confirms that java string is an array?

Tags: java, string

My book "Computer organization and design" of David A Patterson, John Hennessy has a question in "Check yourself" section which confirms that the statement "Strings are just an informal name for single-dimension arrays of characters in C and Java." is true.

I believe this is the case in C, however, in Java, this is completely false. I've been searching in this book's versions of errata, but found nothing.

Am I wrong? I essentially need a help.

Comment: Why don't you have a look at the source code of `java.lang.String`

Comment: Why is it false in your opinion? I do not know really but string could be just a wrapper for byte[] and so on.

Comment: Can you give a pointer of *where* this question appears (chapter/page)? (I'd like to look it up, first to see it in context, and also to have a reason to blow the dust off this tome that stood on my shelf for 15 years now...)

Comment: String wraps an array of chars, but for me is more than that, also you have helpful functions

Comment: @Marco13 see my answer, I mentioned where to find this

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Thanks, obviously the structure changed somewhere (I have the "second edition" ... and there is no CTRL+F :-/ ), but what you quoted indeed seems to only try to convey the basic concept, without differentiating too much between language-specific details.

Comment: @Marco13 wow, it was issued in 1997

Answer (score 4):

Think of a `String` as of a Java concept built around a `char[]` array.

It's a class that contains a `char[]` array and provides a bunch of useful methods.

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
    /** The value is used for character storage. */
    private final char value[];
    ...
}
```

> Strings are just an informal name for single-dimension arrays of characters in C and Java.

I find this statement inaccurate. [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is a fundamental, well-known JDK class, so we can't say it's just an "informal name".

---

I managed to find the chapter "Characters and Strings in Java" (Chapter 2.9) and the "Check yourself" block which OP was referring to. The author broadly describes strings in Java saying only that

> Java uses Unicode for characters

and that

> Strings are a standard Java class with special built-in support and predefined methods for concatenation, comparison, and conversion. Unlike C, Java includes a
>   word that gives the length of the string, similar to Java arrays.

From these lines, we can't draw a reasonable conclusion.

Comment: Yes. But `String` *isn't* itself an array, it is a "struct", where one field is an array.

Comment: I think of `String` the other way around, as a programming interface incidentally implemented using an array.

Comment: Hard to say what the author actually meant to say: string as a concept or as a String class. My bet on the on the first.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

From a pragmatic standpoint, the book is correct. A Java string, in the very end represents an array of char values. But note that this is an implementation detail! The String class could instead use a linked list of Character values internally. That might be horribly inefficient, but still possible. Using an array of char is the natural choice, but not the only one.

But from the compiler constructing point of view, these are two different types. Strings in Java derive from Object. The type String is not at all the same as the type char[] or Character[]. They are not even "related".

So the book is a bit right, and (IMHO) a larger bit plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your perspective.

**Yes, strings are arrays - an implementation perspective**

In the [source code of `java.lang.String`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html) you can clearly find:

```
public final class String
implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
{
/** The value is used for character storage. */
    private final char value[];
//...
```

**No, strings are not arrays - a design perspective**

However, from a design perspective, no good model designer would choose an inheritance (is-a relationship) hierarchy such as

> String extends Array

or in UML:

[image]

Of course, also the designers of Java's `String` class had this in mind and let `String` inherit from `Object` (please see the code above); there is no is-a-relationship to array.